# Data dialog to select Geodatabase

Tags: arcobjects

I need to create a dialog that the user can select a proper Workspace.

Is there a similar to IAddDataDialog, but for workspaces?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you have desktop, you can use IGxDialog.

```
public static IWorkspace Browse4Workspace(int hwnd)
{
    IGxDialog gxDlg = new GxDialogClass();
    gxDlg.ObjectFilter = new GxFilterWorkspacesClass();
    gxDlg.AllowMultiSelect = false;
    IEnumGxObject workspaces;
    IWorkspace ws = null;
    if (gxDlg.DoModalOpen(hwnd, out workspaces) && workspaces != null)
    {
        IGxObject gxObj = workspaces.Next();
        if (gxObj is IGxDatabase)
        {
            IGxDatabase gxDB = gxObj as IGxDatabase;
            if (gxDB != null)
                ws = gxDB.Workspace;
        }
        else if (gxObj is IGxFolder)
        {
            //Todo: figure out how to decide which workspace to get for
            // a particular folder (shapefile, raster etc.)                    
            //IEnumName enumName = ((IGxFolder)gxObj).FileSystemWorkspaceNames;

            // for now just assume we want a shapefile ...
            IWorkspaceFactory wsf = new ESRI.ArcGIS.DataSourcesFile.ShapefileWorkspaceFactoryClass();
            ws = wsf.OpenFromFile(((IGxFile)gxObj).Path, hwnd);
        }
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(workspaces);
    }
    gxDlg.InternalCatalog.Close();
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(gxDlg);
    return ws;
}

private void testToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        IWorkspace ws = Browse4Workspace(this.Handle.ToInt32());
        if (ws != null)
            MessageBox.Show(this, ws.PathName);
        else
            MessageBox.Show(this, "no workspace selected");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message);
    }
}
```